# SQL query (MAX-MIN) is showing wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I am trying to calculate data from my database but first I've noticed strange behavior from the results I get, second, I have trouble making a request that take into account refills.

I have a table with :
Name - DateTime - content

I want to group by day the rows and select the difference of the number to have the consumption.
For example :

```
Name - DateTime - Content
Foo - 22-04-2018 6:00 - 120
Foo - 22-04-2018 10:00 - 119
Foo - 22-04-2018 16:00 - 118
```

The content has decreased, the result should be -2.
Output of my request = -2

Another example :

```
Name - DateTime - Content
Foo - 23-04-2018 6:00 - 50
Foo - 23-04-2018 10:00 - 90
Foo - 23-04-2018 16:00 - 120
```

Here we can notice that the number has increased. It means that instead of a consumption, we have refilled the reserve and the content has increased.
The result should be -70.
Output of my request : 30

My request :

```
SELECT day, 
       Abs(Sum(diffn)) AS totN 
FROM   (SELECT Date(datetime)              AS day, 
               Max(content) - Min(content) AS diffN 
        FROM   logs 
        WHERE  NAME = 'Foo' 
               AND datetime >= '2018-04-22 00:00:00' 
               AND datetime <= '2018-04-23 00:00:00' 
        GROUP  BY Date(datetime)) a 
GROUP  BY day;
```

But for the second example I have 30 as a result instead of 70, I don't know why...
I would like your help to change my request and take refills into account so that I get the results I want.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using `mysql` or `oracle` ?? Please tag only one.

Comment: I edited it, sorry

Comment: Please edit your question and show us clear input and output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the Prefix by comparing the highest and the lowest value, the time (hour) included. I'm using the 'CASE' function with two subqueries here.

Maybe you'll need to turn the year-month-day around, because I'm using the german datetime-format.

```
SET @datetime = '2018-04-22';

SELECT date(datetime) as day
    ,(CASE WHEN
     (SELECT content FROM logs WHERE date(datetime) = @datetime ORDER BY datetime LIMIT 1)
        >
     (SELECT content FROM logs WHERE date(datetime) = @datetime ORDER BY datetime desc LIMIT 1)
       THEN min(content) - max(content)
       ELSE max(content) - min(content) END) as diffN
    FROM logs 

    WHERE Name = 'Foo' AND date(datetime) = @datetime
    GROUP BY day(datetime)
    ORDER BY datetime
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you grouping it second time:

Ideally this should work:

```
SELECT Date(datetime)              AS day, 
       Max(content) - Min(content) AS diffN 
FROM   logs 
WHERE  NAME = 'Foo' 
       AND datetime >= '2018-04-22 00:00:00' 
       AND datetime <= '2018-04-23 00:00:00' 
GROUP  BY Date(datetime)
```

Result of this query will contain only 2 rows - 1 for 22th and 1 for 23rd day. There is no need of grouping it again by day

Comment: That's true i didn't need it, but after the changes the result is still wrong for the second example. Do you have any idea how to display the refills in a good way?

Comment: Try debugging it.
instead on max - min, select these values separately as well and check if thats the value you want.
SELECT date(datetime) as day, max(content) as max,min(content) as min, max(content) - min(content) as diffN

Comment: Thank you Rahul it was a good idea I didn't think about it. It shows for the second example that it takes 90 and 120 instead of 50 and 120. It doesn't take the minimal value for the day, it's odd...

Comment: you can try few more queries to debug: for ex: try removing where name='Foo' condition or list all the values for that day (without grouping).
Check if you are getting the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT day(datetime) as day, max(content) - min(content) as diffN
FROM logs 
WHERE Name = 'Foo' 
AND datetime >= '2018-04-23 00:00:00' 
AND datetime <= '2018-04-24 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY day(datetime)
```

Also, change the date filters it should be betweeen 23 and 24.

Comment: That's true i didn't need it, but after the changes the result is still wrong for the second example. Do you have any idea how to display the refills in a good way? The filters were just for the example they are not representative

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to establish the first and last datetime and their associated content. For example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (name varchar(3), dt datetime, content int);
insert into t values
('Foo' , '2018-04-22 06:00:00', 120),
('Foo' , '2018-04-22 10:00:00', 119),
('Foo' , '2018-04-22 16:00:00', 118),
('Foo' , '2018-04-23 06:00:00', 50),
('Foo' , '2018-04-23 10:00:00', 90),
('Foo' , '2018-04-23 16:00:00', 120);

select s.name,lastinday,firstinday,lastinday - firstinday
from 
(
select name,dt, content lastinday
from t
where dt = (Select max(dt) from t t1 where t1.name = t.name and date(t1.dt) = date(t.dt))
) s
join
(
select name,dt, content firstinday
from t
where dt = (Select min(dt) from t t1 where t1.name = t.name and date(t1.dt) = date(t.dt))
) t
on t.name = s.name and date(t.dt) = date(s.dt);

+------+-----------+------------+------------------------+
| name | lastinday | firstinday | lastinday - firstinday |
+------+-----------+------------+------------------------+
| Foo  |       118 |        120 |                     -2 |
| Foo  |       120 |         50 |                     70 |
+------+-----------+------------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```